# Styling a Select using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering if anyone knew of a jquery select box plugin to achieve the same type of styling found here: http://www.tinyprints.com/product/5023/thank_you_cards_dahlia_blooms.html ?

You can see the look I was going for here: http://louisstephens.cc/forrst/dropdown.jpg

**Edit: Let me rephrase my question: Does anyone know how to achieve spacing in a select like in the link above?**

Comment: There are millions of select box plugins for jquery.  Just google and find one you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of great [list](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/select-box) box plugins. This [one](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/FancySelectbox) looks like the one you would like and is my personal favorite.